# VMware ESXi: how to choose between VMI Paravirtualization and 64-bit?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

VMware ESXi 4 supports VMI paravirtualization for 32-bit OS but not for 64-bit OS. For performance consideration, is it better to use a 32-bit Ubuntu Server guest without paravirtualization or a 64-bit one with VMI paravirtualization?

- Hardware: Core 2 Quad, 8 GB RAM
- Workload: Software development/testing, webserver, database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wouldn't use VMI at all as VMWare are retiring support for it this year or next - read about this [HERE](http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/2009/09/vmi-retirement.html).